# How to import an image based on a variable value or value-of result

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

i'm new to xsl-fo.
In my problem there are 3 sibling tags, one of them has an attribute. I have to print the one with the attribute first and then the other two.
My problem is that my results aren't showing and i've tried when and if.
Heres my code:

```
             <fo:block>
                <xsl:for-each select="platforms/platform">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@highestRated">
                            <xsl:value-of select="platform"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
                ! Also available on
                <xsl:for-each select="platforms/platform">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(@*)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="platform"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:block>
```

and heres an example of the siblings:

```
<platforms>
  <platform>PC</platform>
  <platform highestRated="true">PS3</platform>
  <platform>X360</platform>
</platforms>
```

i can't just use them in the order they appear here because each set of siblings are in a different order.
I also get no errors and the rest of the document displays perfectly, they just won't show the results.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, your main problem is that you have `select="platform"` which is looking for an element `/platforms/platform/platform` which doesn't exist. Also an `xsl:choose` with only one `xsl:when` is the same as an `xsl:if`. (It is useful to use `xsl:when` if you want a *else* condition, which `xsl:if` doesn't provide. Use `xsl:choose` / `xsl:when` /  `xsl:otherwise` instead.) But in this case you may as well select only the elements you want using a *predicate*; then there is no need for a conditional.

Here is some code that does what you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!-- New document created with EditiX at Wed Mar 21 21:51:52 GMT 2012 -->

<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

  <xsl:variable name="nl">
<xsl:text>
  </xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="platforms/platform[@highestRated]">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:text>! Also available on</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="platforms/platform[not(@highestRated)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </fo:block>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
PS3
! Also available on
PC
X360
</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<xsl:value-of select="platform"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You could also be a little more efficient by using an xsl:if rather than xsl:choose, but that is a minor point